# Displaying error instead of null values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am building up a site in PHP which takes input of more than 20 fields from user. Hardly 3-4 field values are compulsory, rest can be left blank. I want to display a custom error message instead of blank or zero or null while displaying these values. How can this be done? I am using MySQL as backend.

Comment: Do you happen to know `foreach` statement? And what about $_POST array?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the $_POST array.

In that case you could just do:

```
$errors = array();
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value)) {
        $_POST[$key] = "Custom error message"; // Or place it in an apart array like:
        $errors[$key] = "Custom error message";
    }
}
```

You can also choose to print the message to the screen immediately. That's up to you.

Besides, did you ever consider a Validation library like:

```
http://kohanaframework.org/guide/security.validation
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$var1 = 'Foo';
$var2 = '';
$var3 = NULL;

echo ( ! empty($var1)) ? $var1 : 'Not set!'; // Foo
echo ( ! empty($var2)) ? $var2 : 'Not set!'; // Not set!
echo ( ! empty($var3)) ? $var3 : 'Not set!'; // Not set!

/**
 * Alternative function solution based on OP's comment:
 */

function output($str)
{
    echo ( ! empty($str)) ? $str : 'Not set!';
    return TRUE;
}

output($var1); // Foo
output($var2); // Not set!
output($var3); // Not set!
```

Comment: Is there any other solution so that just one function makes all null values an error message, instead of doing it for all variables

Comment: There's lots of ways to do it. I've edited my answer above so it uses a custom function called `output()` to echo the handed variable (if not empty) or echo `Not set!` otherwise.

Comment: You could also change the function to return the variable you hand to it, incase you don't want to echo straight away.

Comment: I want just 4 lines of function code so that whenever any null value is encountered it automatically displays an error.

Comment: What? I don't understand you... maybe edit your original question to include some code so I have more idea what you're on about?

Comment: Could whoever it was explain the -1 please? What I did wrong? How I could improve? My answer does exactly what (I think) the OP wanted and I even added a second way after the OP's comment...